# Get Home page url in outside magento php file

Tags: magento-1.9, url, base-url

I want to get magento home page url in outside magento file I have added below code in my custom file pdf.php

```
require_once("app/Mage.php");
Mage::app();
$connectionWrite   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$product['inv_ID'] = $inv_ID = $_GET['id']; // Get the inventory ID
$_product          = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($inv_ID);
if ($_product->getShortDescription()) {
    $product['Ad_Line'] = $_product->getShortDescription();
    $product['price']   = $_product->getFinalPrice();
    $product['image']   = $_product->getImage();
    echo $url                = Mage::getBaseUrl()
    exit;
}
```

I am getting below output

```
http://localhost/xxxproject/pdf.php/
```

How can I get direct home page url like below without using $_SERVER

```
http://localhost/xxxproject/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to get home page from Admin site?

```
$storeId = 10;
$homepage = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/secure/base_url', $storeId);
```

FULL SCRIPTS ARE

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
  $app = Mage::app('admin');
  $storeId = 10; 
  $homepage = Mage::getStoreConfig('web/secure/base_url', $storeId);
  echo 'homepage' . $homepage;

Comment: Yes, It's working with some minor changes. Thanks